# jquery adding iteration to clone

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has two buttons one is to enter new rows of empty input text boxes awaiting user input and the other I would like for the user to be able to duplicate data they just entered. I do not want the data to be automatically duplicated I want the user to have to click the button for the information to be duplicated / cloned. The names of the values must be able to iterate because this data will be submitted to a database using mysql using for each.

The code listed is wrapped in a php while loop.

I can not figure out how to add iteration to the jquery clone attribute. Additionally, I only want one row to be cloned at a time.

This is what I have so far. Currently if I have 2 rows 2 rows are cloned, 4 rows then 4 rows are cloned etc. I only want one row to be added at a time. And there is obviously no iteration.

I am extremely novice when it comes to jquery so any help is appreciated.

Update:

I have tried to assign a row number to each row and as long as the "Add new row" is added one click at a time the clone will work. However, if the Add new row is clicked twice then two rows will be duplicated.

```js
<script>
 $("#button<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
    var count = $("input").length + 1;
    
    $("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>").prepend("<div id=rowNumber"+count+"><input type='text' value='<?php echo $itemid; ?>' name='itemid[" + count + "]'><input type='text' name='qty[" + count + "]'><div>");
  
  $("#buttonClone<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
        $("#rowNumber" + count).clone().appendTo("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>");
    });

}); 

</script>
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10px 0px;">
<div style="font-size:1.2em;">
<?php echo $lineid.") ".$itemid; ?>
</div>

<button id="button<?php echo $lineid; ?>">Add new row</button>
<button id="buttonClone<?php echo $lineid; ?>">Clone</button> 
<br>



<form action='#' method='post'>
 <div id="part<?php echo $lineid; ?>"></div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Update II:

This is how I would like the code to be however the issue here is that every time the dup button is clicked the form is submitted rather than a new line added. I do not understand how to give the duplicate button a unique id that matches the id of a row that was added without including it in the form attribute.

```js
<script>
 $("#button<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
    var count = $("input").length + 1;
    
    $("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>").prepend("<div id=rowNumber"+count+"><button id=buttonClone"+ count +">Dup</button><input type='text' value='<?php echo $itemid; ?>' name='itemid[" + count + "]'><input type='text' name='qty[" + count + "]'><div>");
  
  $("#buttonClone<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
        $("#rowNumber" + count).clone().appendTo("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>");
    });

}); 

</script>
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10px 0px;">
<div style="font-size:1.2em;">
<?php echo $lineid.") ".$itemid; ?>
</div>

<button id="button<?php echo $lineid; ?>">Add new row</button>

<br>



<form action='#' method='post'>
 <div id="part<?php echo $lineid; ?>"></div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Update III:

By removing the form attribute I can accomplish exactly what I am wanting with exception to iterating to the next value while using the clone attribute.

I have no idea how to accomplish that. I saw a post somewhere on google that used next in some manner but it was way beyond my capabilities.

```js
<script>
 $("#button<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
    var count = $("input").length + 1;
    
    $("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>").prepend("<div id=rowNumber" + count + "><button id=buttonClone" + count + ">Dup</button><input type='text' value='<?php echo $itemid; ?>' name='itemid[" + count + "]'><input type='text' name='qty[" + count + "]'><div>");
  
  $("#buttonClone"+count).click(function(){
        $("#rowNumber" + count).clone().appendTo("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>");
    });

}); 

</script>
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10px 0px;">
<div style="font-size:1.2em;">
<?php echo $lineid.") ".$itemid; ?>
</div>

<button id="button<?php echo $lineid; ?>">Add new row</button>

<br>




 <div id="part<?php echo $lineid; ?>"></div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Update IV:

I understand that "var count = $("input").length;" gets the length of inputs and I understand doing that outside the click and I think I understand that I have added the iteration inside the click I think that is what I have done now but it still is not working. The clone is still not picking up an incremented name value.

```js
<script>
 
 
 
 var count = $("input").length;
 
 $("#button<?php echo $lineid; ?>").click(function(){
  
 var count = $("input[id^=buttonClone]").length +1;   
    
    $("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>").prepend("<div id=rowNumber" + count + "><button id=buttonClone" + count + ">Dup</button><input id='buttonClone" + count + "' type='text' value='<?php echo $itemid; ?>' name='itemid[" + count + "]'><input type='text' name='qty[" + count + "]'><div>");  
   
  $("#buttonClone"+count).click(function(){
        $("#rowNumber" + count).clone().appendTo("#part<?php echo $lineid; ?>");
   
   
    }); 


});  

</script>
```

```html
<div style="margin: 10px 0px;">
<div style="font-size:1.2em;">
<?php echo $lineid.") ".$itemid; ?>
</div>

<button id="button<?php echo $lineid; ?>">Add new row</button>

<br>




 <div id="part<?php echo $lineid; ?>"></div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Example of desired results:

```html
<button id="button1">Add new row</button>
<br>
<div id="part1">
<div id="rowNumber4">
 <button id="buttonClone4">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone4" type="text" value="" name="itemid[4]">//value added by using the add new button
 <input type="text" name="qty[4]">
</div>
<div id="rowNumber5">
 <button id="buttonClone5">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone5" type="text" value="somevalueone" name="itemid[5]">//Dup button used values added from rowNumber3 - part1
 <input type="text" name="qty[5]">
</div>
<div id="rowNumber3">
 <button id="buttonClone3">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone3" type="text" value="somevalueone" name="itemid[3]">//Dup button used values added from rowNumber1 - part1
 <input type="text" name="qty[3]">
</div>
<div id="rowNumber2">
 <button id="buttonClone2">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone2" type="text" value="somevalueone" name="itemid[2]">//Dup button used values added from rowNumber1 - part1
 <input type="text" name="qty[2]">
</div>
<div id="rowNumber1">
 <button id="buttonClone1">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone1" type="text" value="somevalueone" name="itemid[1]">//value added by using the add new button
 <input type="text" name="qty[1]">
</div>
</div>
<button id="button1">Add new row</button>
<br>
<div id="part2">
<div id="rowNumber2">
 <button id="buttonClone2">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone2" type="text" value="" name="itemid[2]">//value added by using the add new button
 <input type="text" name="qty[2]">
</div>
<div id="rowNumber1">
 <button id="buttonClone1">Dup</button>
 <input id="buttonClone1" type="text" value="somevalueone" name="itemid[1]">//value added by suing the add new button
 <input type="text" name="qty[1]">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `<?php echo $lineid; ?>` return a `.className`?

Comment: Yes it does return the class name

Comment: You are cloning all of the elements with that `.className`.

Comment: Should click on both `button` elements prepend element to same `div`?

Comment: What is expected result of click on `#buttonClone`?

Comment: an individual row should be duplicated / cloned. however if it is it must have a new input name for the text input

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: I do not know how to add the next value in the iteration for the name of the new input that is generated when using clone.

Comment: `$("input").length` gets the `.length` of all `<input>` elements in `document`. You can define `count` variable outside of `click` event, use selector `"input[id^=buttonClone]"` to select element where `id` begins with `"buttonClone"`, `var count = $("input[id^=buttonClone]").length`. Increment `count` within `click` handler.

Comment: I have tried all day to get it correct and I still can not. I understand how the input length gets the length of all inputs and I feel that I understand how to pass that new value into the click event for clone but it is not incriminating. There is only one new row being added when the clone button is activated but still no incremented names for the new/cloned inputs being added in the form.

Comment: `php` portion should only be run once. Still not sure about expected result of `.clone()`?

Comment: Have you tried suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352070/jquery-adding-iteration-to-clone?noredirect=1#comment69909822_41352070 ?

Comment: The clone is for adding a new row with the same values as previously entered by the user while generating uniquely named input fields into the same form. The rows are generated by using the "Add new row" button. The purpose is to allow the same input over and over but add new unique input names so they can be added to the database individually using the php for each loop.

Comment: You are appending elements with duplicate `buttonClone + count` `id`s to `document` at `<button id=buttonClone" + count + ">Dup</button><input id='buttonClone" + count + "' type='text' value='<?php echo $itemid; ?>' name='itemid[" + count + "]'>`. `id` of element in `document` should be unique.

Comment: I do understand that they need to be unique but I do not now how to achieve that for the clone process. I posted an example of how the generated html portion of the could should look like. Maybe that will help in understanding my end goals.

Comment: Is `#part2` included at original `html`?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate `id`s in `document` adjust dynamically created `<button>` element `id` to `class`, while still setting `name` attribute of `<input>` elements to `count` variable .

Attach `click` event for `".buttonClone"` `<button>` elements to parent `#part1` element, outside scope of `#button` `click` handler. 
Use `.each()`, `.replace()` to replace digit at `name` attributes of cloned element `input` elements with value of `$("#part2 > .rowNumber").length + 1`. Substitute `.prependTo()` for `.appendTo()` within delegated `click` event handler.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  var count = $("#part1 > .rowNumber").length + 1;

  $("#part1")
  .prepend(
    "<div class='rowNumber'>"
    + "<button class='buttonClone'>Dup</button>"
    + "<input class='buttonClone' type='text' "
    + "value='' name='itemid[" + count + "]'>"
    + "<input type='text' name='qty[" + count + "]'>"
    + "</div>");

});

$("#part1").on("click", ".buttonClone", function() {

  var count = $("#part2 > .rowNumber").length + 1;
  var clone = $("#part1 > .rowNumber:last-child").clone();

  clone
  .find("input")
  .each(function(index, el) {
    el.name = el.name.replace(/\d+/, count);
  })
  .end()
  .prependTo("#part2");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="button">click</button><br>
part1<br>
<div id="part1"></div><br/>
part2<br/>
<div id="part2"></div>
```

Comment: That is way over my head. However, it still is not functioning as expected. There is only one 'click' button. Each part must have its own click button. Each dup button needs to be relative to unique part. In your example anything dup in part one is added to part two and anything that was duplicated by using the dup button does nothing. Everything is incrementing though. Once I get this worked out without php is it feasible to wrap it all in a while loop? Each form will have a different set of parts. IE part 1, part 2 part 3 so on and so on. If not then I need to change the logic here.

Comment: @jlewis504 Should click on `<input type="button">` having `.value` `"Dup"` append an `<input type="button">` to the `#partN` element?